# SFMCSdk doesn’t display notifications on Android 12

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

We implement SFMCSdk v8.0.9 in our Android app in order to send push notifications to our customers. We implement the case with using multiple SDK:

```
class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
  override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {

    if (PushMessageManager.isMarketingCloudPush(message)) {
      SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
        sdk.mp {
          it.pushMessageManager.handleMessage(message)
        }
    }
  } else {
    //Not from Marketing Cloud.  Must handle yourself.
  }
}
```

The code work without any problem on Android versions prior 12, but on version 12 notification is received, but not shown. Has anyone encountered this issue?